# How to get tidyr's complete to work with a variable specifying columns?

Tags: r, tidyr

Here is some code using `complete`:

```
dat <- data.frame(a=c(1,NA), b=c(3,NA), val=c(20,30))
dat %>% complete(a, b, fill=list(val=0))

# A tibble: 4 x 3
      a     b   val
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     3    20
2     1    NA     0
3    NA     3     0
4    NA    NA    30
```

How do I make a function that takes the columns to complete?  Here is a failed attempt:

```
foo_func <- function(dat, the_cols) {
  dat %>% complete(all_of(the_cols), fill=list(val=0))
}
foo_func(dat, c('a', 'b'))

Error: Join columns must be present in data.
x Problem with `all_of(the_cols)`.
```

Here's another:

```
foo_func <- function(dat, the_cols) {
  dat %>% complete(!!the_cols, fill=list(val=0))
}
foo_func(dat, c('a', 'b'))

Error: Join columns must be present in data.
x Problem with `<chr>`
```

I want `the_cols` to be a character vector, because this is in an existing body of code that passes things around that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could convert to `sym`bols and use `!!!`

```
foo_func <- function(dat, the_cols) {
  dat %>% complete(!!! rlang::syms(the_cols), fill=list(val=0))
}
```

-checking

```
foo_func(dat, c('a', 'b'))
# A tibble: 4 x 3
#      a     b   val
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1     3    20
#2     1    NA     0
#3    NA     3     0
#4    NA    NA    30
```

Comment: Amazing, thanks. You've answered so many meta-programming questions like these, I wonder if there is a good resource for it. I can't tell when to use !!, !!!, all_of, as.sym, etc. etc. I've casually read https://adv-r.hadley.nz. It's written well, but I don't see the section focused on this.

Comment: @dfrankow can you check the vignettes of [tidyverse](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/). It may have some articles.

Comment: How to make it work with unquoted names ?